# Polymer - is it possible to substitute bootstrap with it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I used polymer paper elements individually before, but is it possible to use it to build a whole responsive website(nothing extraordinary, just a usual website)? I'm asking because it does not have grids, containers, and I don't quite understand the iron-flex-layout or whatever. Anyone used it like this before? Is the outcome good and responsive? I guess the Polymer Starter Kit would be the starting point.

Comment: Instead of downvoting this question, I will just vote to close it. If you want to build a "website", you can use either bootstrap or polymer. Both have good documentation and I think Bootstrap is more popular because of easy learning curve.

Comment: Answer to this would be opinion based and hence not fit for SO :-)

Comment: Although this is opinion based, but for those new to polymer, they do need some opinions, these opinion must based on facts.

Answer (score 0):

> Answer to this would be opinion based
>
> ---- by Aniket

1. Polymer's [compatibility browser](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/compatibility.html) is very hight, but bootstrap's [browser support](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support) is very wide.So, if you use Polymer you can think less and do more with better feature,like css3 thing.
2. Polymer's element is alway styled, if you use polymer with bootstrap, you will barely use bootstrap component.So, the most important part of bootsrap is grid,helper utils(e.g. text-info, small, p-a-x in bs4).
3. In modern browser with better css support, actually, you drop bootstrap grid and use css flex. [Browser support flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) almost match Polymer's browser requirement, so you can leverage the [power of flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
4. That's why [polymer elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements) work with [iron-flex-layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-flex-layout).
5. Bootstrap's helper class still useful, but you don't have to import all boostrap, you can copy and past to you shared css, now,[Bootstrap 4 alpha](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/) is available with more helper class like `{p|m}-{atblr}-{0|md}`.

BTW, this is how I use bootstrap in my project.for example

```
<paper-material class="p-a-0 layout horizontal">
```